# How to mock external service when testing a NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, koa, superagent, koa2

I have JSON API built with koa which I am trying to cover with integration tests.

**A simple test would look like this:**

```
      describe("GET: /users", function() {
        it ("should respond", function (done) {
          request(server)
          .get('/api/users')
          .expect(200, done);
        });
      });
```

Now the issue comes when the actions behind a controller - lets say saveUser at POST /users - use external resources. For instance I need to validate the users phone number.

**My controller looks like this:**

```
  save: async function(ctx, next) {
    const userFromRequest = await parse(ctx);
    try {
      // validate data
      await ctx.repo.validate(userFromRequest);

      // validate mobile code
      await ctx.repo.validateSMSCode(
        userFromRequest.mobile_number_verification_token,
        userFromRequest.mobile_number.prefix +  userFromRequest.mobile_number.number
      );

      const user = await ctx.repo.create(userFromRequest);

      return ctx.data(201, { user });
    } catch (e) {
      return ctx.error(422, e.message, e.meta);
    }
  }
```

I was hoping to be able to mock the `ctx.repo` on the request object but I can't seem to able to get a hold on it from test, which means that my tests are actually hitting the phone number verification service.

**Are there any ways I could go around hitting that verification service ?**

Comment: Try to find the way to modify the `ctx` in you test. You would be able to replace the `ctx.repo` before running the actual controller to your own mock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a mockup library like https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery?

Typically, when writing tests requiring external services, I mock the service client library module. For example, using mocha:

```
mockery = require('mockery');
repo = require('your-repo-module');

before(function() {
  mockery.enable();

  repo.validateSMSCode = function() {...};

  mockery.registerMock('your-repo-module', repo);
}
```

This way, every time you require your-repo-module, the mocked module will be loaded rather than the original one. Until you disable the mock, obviously...

Answer (score -1):

> `app.context` is the prototype from which `ctx` is created from. You may
>   add additional properties to `ctx` by editing `app.context`. This is
>   useful for adding properties or methods to `ctx` to be used across your
>   entire `app`, which may be more performant (no middleware) and/or easier
>   (fewer `require()`s) at the expense of relying more on `ctx`, which could
>   be considered an anti-pattern.

```java
app.context.someProp = "Some Value";

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.someProp);
});
```

For your sample your re-define `app.context.repo.validateSMSCode` like this, assuming that you have following setup lines in your test:

```java
import app from '../app'
import supertest from 'supertest'

app.context.repo.validateSMSCode = async function(ctx, next) {
  // Your logic here.
};    

const request = supertest.agent(app.listen())
```

After re-defining `app.context.repo.validateSMSCode` method that your will define in your test, will work, instead of original method.

- https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/v2.x/docs/api/index.md#appcontext
- https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/652